# How to Secure + Patch Orchard CMS & avoid Wordpress style hacks

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am looking to roll Orchard CMS out on a greenfield project.

Wordpress, a similar product built in PHP, has a lot of issues with being targeted by hackers - and has various plugins and techniques to help secure it. Regular patching is also required.

What is the recommended approach / best practice to keep Orchard secure & patched?

- Is there any best practice on deploying it securely?
- Is it some how inherently more secure than WP?
- What is the recommended strategy for patching & security & can it be done automatically?
- Are there any security related modules you'd recommend?
- What track record does it have here compared to WP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard has several advantages to Word Press

1. The ASP.NET framework provides a lot of built in support to stop SQL
   injection and other common attacks
2. Orchard Provides anti-forgery tokens in its forms (that you can make use of in yours)
3. By the very nature that is a less common framework than WP, there will be
   significantly fewer targeted attacks on it
4. Patching is generally just downloading any copying over the top - modules have a
   "Migrations" system that will automatically update them to the
   latest version when you download.

Other than that I would say that the raft of standard ASP.NET security best practice is more than applicable to Orchard (turning on custom errors and the like). If you want a good source for MVC security understanding you might start with Dominic Baier's http://leastprivilege.com/